# Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync not working

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am porting some parts of a WPF application to a windowless library for use in other projects.  There are some methods in the original code which get called using `Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync()`.  Since this is not available in a plain class library, I made a wrapper for it, and in the library I'm attempting to use `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync` instead - I set a break and see the call being made, but the passed method never executes.  What am I missing?

Comment: `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` is not necessarily the same as `Application.Current.Dispatcher`. You should save `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` somewhere when on the UI thread (e.g., in the constructor) and then use the saved value.

Comment: @Noseratio, I realized they weren't the same - the problem is that the library version of the code may or may not be used with a UI.  MSDN says the Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher will be created for the current thread if none exists; and I'm not getting any NRE or anything of the like, the method simply never gets called.

Comment: Then you should save `SynchronizationContext.Current` (if any), then queue a callback with `SynchronizationContext.Post`. This is a portable way of dealing with this.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need two versions of the dispatcher wrapper: One is for UI applications that internally uses Application.Current.Dispatcher. The other is for non-UI applications that calls the delegate to be invoked directly without an internal dispatcher. A simple example of this idea is the following code:

```
public class DispatcherWrapper
{
    private readonly Action<Action> _dispatch;

    public DispatcherWrapper(Action<Action> dispatch)
    {
        _dispatch = dispatch;
    }

    public void Dispatch(Action action)
    {
        _dispatch(action);
    }
}

public class Application
{
    internal void SomeCode()
    {
        // A UI application would call...
        var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        var dispatcherWrapper = new DispatcherWrapper(action => dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action));

        // A non-UI application would call...
        dispatcherWrapper = new DispatcherWrapper(action => action());

        // The library code would call..
        dispatcherWrapper.Dispatch(() => { 
            // This code runs on the UI thread in UI apps and on any thread in non-UI apps.
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.